# Postgres: aggregation function that returns a column

Tags: sql, postgresql

In postgres, when I call a function on some data, like so:

```sql
select f(col_nums) from tbl_name
where col_str = '12345'
```

then function `f` will be applied on each row where `col_str = '12345'`.

On the other hand, if I call an aggregation function on some data, like so:

```sql
select g_agg(col_nums) from tbl_name
where col_str = '12345'
```

then the function `g_agg` will be called on the the entire column but will result in a single value.

**Q:** How can I make a function that will be applied on the entire column and return a column of the same size while at the same time being aware of all the values in the the subset?

For example, can I create a function to calculate cumulative sum?

```sql
select *, sum_accum(col_nums) as cs from tbl_name
where col_str = '12345'
```

such that the result of the above query would look like this:

```
 col_str | more_cols | col_numbers | cs
---------+-----------+-------------+----
  12345  |    567    |     1       |  1
  12345  |    568    |     2       |  3
  12345  |    569    |     3       |  6
  12345  |    570    |     4       | 10
```

Is there no choice but to pass a sub-query result to a function and then `join` with the original table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html)

> A window function performs a calculation across a set of table rows
>   that are somehow related to the current row. This is comparable to the
>   type of calculation that can be done with an aggregate function. But
>   unlike regular aggregate functions, use of a window function does not
>   cause rows to become grouped into a single output row — the rows
>   retain their separate identities. Behind the scenes, the window
>   function is able to access more than just the current row of the query
>   result.

e.g.

```
select *, sum(col_nums) OVER(PARTITION BY T.COLX, T.COLY) as cs 
from tbl_name T
where col_str = '12345'
```

Note that it is the addition on a `over clause` that changes an aggregate from its traditional use to a `window function`:

> the OVER clause causes it to be treated as a window function and
>   computed across an appropriate set of rows

In the `over clause` has a `partition by` (analogous to `group by`) which controls the `window` that the calculations are performed in; and it also allows an `order by` which is valid for some functions but not all.

```
select *
   -- running sum using an order by
 , sum(col_nums) OVER(PARTITION BY T.COLX ORDER BY T.COLY) as cs 

   -- but count does not permit ordering
 , count(*) OVER(PARTITION BY T.COLX) as cs_count
from tbl_name T
where col_str = '12345'
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The function that you want is a cumulative sum.  This is handled by window functions:

```
select t.*, sum(col_nums) over (order by more_cols) as cs
from tbl_name t
where col_str = '12345';
```

I am guessing that the order by sequence is defined by the second column.  It can be any column including `col_nums`.

You can do this for all values of `col_str` at the same time, using the `partition by` clause:

```
select t.*, sum(col_nums) over (partition by col_str order by more_cols) as cs
from tbl_name t
```

Comment: Thanks, Gordon. You and @Used_By_Already gave similar answers, but I gotta give it to him since he got here first.